# Can chatbot answer questions for which it does not have an inbuilt answer?

Tags: chatbot

I am new to AI and carry little knowledge about it. Apologies in advance if question sounds silly.

I need to build a conversational bot which answers user queries. However, there are situations where it does not have an answer to user utterances. Can a bot be made intelligent enough to handle such scenarios? 
For example, my bot can answer question related to downloading an application. But I haven't trained it for answering how to signup in the app. Can this bot still be made intelligent enough to answer such type of questions?

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer is no, that would require general artificial intelligence which does not exist currently.

However, there is a nuance in that it may be possible to create a dialogue system that makes a best guess by learning from some conversation bank. However, this system would not be able to learn anything that does not exist in the data you train it with.